# Why does Whoscall database update fail on ADSL 2M/64K?

Tags: updates, whoscall

Why does Whoscall database update fail on ADSL 2M/64K Wi-Fi?

Comment: When talking about third party apps please always include the app store link as apps can have different names in other localizations.

Comment: I was going to but was afraid of being kicked off for spamming. https://whoscall.com/ has both major app store links. Two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 0):

Because Whoscall assumes a slow network is no network.

因 Whoscall 誤以為網路慢就是沒有網路。

Turn on your cellular data and it will succeed.

開啟行動數據就會成功。